# In Codeigniter form_error('option[x]') is not working. How can i solve this??

Tags: codeigniter, validation

In Codeigniter  **set_value('option[".$i."]') ** is working fine, but  **form_error('option[".$i."]')** is not working. [where $i is 1 to 10]. How can I solve this??

Comment: can you share more information?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1icGOwVtUn1ejdIA-HNc8IML4JqwHTFj6/view

Answer (score 0):

I think its a string closing issue. 
u can change that with the following

form_error('option['.$i.']')

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1icGOwVtUn1ejdIA-HNc8IML4JqwHTFj6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are u sure that u loaded the form helper. It need to load to use the form_error().

Make sure u have specified the error message in set_rules() correctly

Also, since u are using array as field name just refer this also https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#using-arrays-as-field-names

Comment: yes I have used form helper and set_value('option['.$i.']') is working. but why form_ error('option['.$i.']') is not working i don't know. but if I use form_ error('option[]') without any value inside this then this is working and same error is showing every field.

Comment: Can u paste the code u written in the set_rules() in controller for this?

Comment: if u want to show error message for each form element separately then u need to write the rules for each element separately.
ie, in controller u need to give **$this- form_validation- set_rules('expenditure['.$i.']','Expenditure','trim|required');**
 Inside view u have to give 
**form_error('expenditure['.$i.']');**

Comment: **set_value** does not need form validation library rules to work. It is a function of form helper which can work independently by looking the value in $_POST. If a rule is given then it work along with that ([ref](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#set_value)). But **form_error** is depend on rules given in form validation ([ref](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_error)).